# Create and fill drop-down in JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I use mvc2, and I have model with data that I need to have in drop-down.

When i making drop-down in View it is not problem I use:

```
<%: Html.DropDownList("cbDrop",   Model.Drop,  "",  new { @class = "dropdown" })%>
```

But now I need to fill drop-down in JS file.

First I try to use:

```
@Html.DropDownList("cbDrop",   Model.Drop,  "",  new { @class = "dropdown" })
```

After I getting errors I try first to get value of model like:

```
var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))
```

But i get error in firebug for `@` is illegal character.

Can I dynamically create drop-down in `JS` file and fill it with model value?
Thanx

Comment: it is not possible to use razor helper methods in js files. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @MajoB Thanx for answer. I resolve my problem on other way, I write method in controller that send me data like JSON object, and than i generate dropdown in JS.